# Why we not use () while calling function in EventListener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new to JavaScript. I read a code which is:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate);
function displayDate() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
```

I read the documentation, in this I get that the second parameter of `addEventListener` would be a function like the bellow (here after function we use `()` brackets)

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
});
```

according to my knowledge, we must use `()` after a function which is not in the first example. Even if I use than it doesn't work. So my question is why we can't use `()` if we create a separate function. I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 3):

The parentheses mean different things in these scenarios. The parentheses that go after the `function` keyword denote a list of arguments that you provide to the function, e.g. `function(a, b, c)` signifies that the function takes 3 arguments, `a`, `b`, and `c`. The parentheses that go after `displayDate` represent the fact that you are **calling** the function with no parameters, and passing the return value to `addEventListener`. Since `displayDate` returns `undefined`, you are essentially setting `undefined` as an event listener, which will do nothing.

Comment: thanks for answer ... but if i do this than it also not work as it expected to do.
`var test = "hello"
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate(test));

function displayDate(param) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
  alert(param)
}`

Comment: Well yes because you're still calling the function, and it's not returning another function. `addEventListener` requires a **function** as the second argument, not the value that you get from calling a function.